# Dynamically adding a new property to a class

Tags: dynamic

I want to add a property to a class in runtime.

```
public class abc
{
   public int a {get;set;}
   public int b {get;set;}
   public int c {get;set;}
}

public void Main()
{   
    abc a = new abc();
    // i want object 'a' have d(int) property
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve that?

Comment: what is language?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you need to add a property at runtime? Maybe there is a better solution. Please add that info to your question (and format the code, while you are there)